# Convert input string contain font in list

Tags: python

I want to convert a input text "" contain in the font list "original":

```
text = input("Enter text: ")

#Enter text: 

original = ["",
            "0123456789",
            "",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"]

replace = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"]

originalMap = original[0]
replaceMap = replace[0]
result = ""
for i in text:
    if i in originalMap:
        result += replaceMap[originalMap.index(i)]
                
    else:   
        result += i

print("Converted: " +result)
```

#Converted: APPLE

But I can't convert with another font in the list "original" such as , , ...

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: It's because of this `originalMap = original[0]` try iterating the other list items as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the possible mappings in one structure, from each letter of the 4 fonts to the classic one

Use a dict for that. And give 4 times the mapping: one font > classic font, that will make a dict of 62*4=248 mappings

```
text = "A!"

original = ["",
            "0123456789",
            "",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"]
replaceAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

originalMap = {}
for alphabet in original:
    originalMap.update(dict(zip(alphabet, replaceAlphabet)))
```

Then for the use, use `dict.get`, it'll search for the value in the dict, if it don't find it it'll use the default value, set `char` too for the default value => pick the corresponding value OR use the key itself

```
result = "".join(originalMap.get(char, char) for char in text)

print("Converted: " + result)
# Converted: APPLE!012
```

Comment: It words Sir, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.translate` function to replace characters:

```
original = ["",
            "0123456789",
            "",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"]

# This can just be a string, no need for it to be a list of strings
replace = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

# Create a mapping from char codes to the replacment
mapping = {ord(char):replace[index] for font in original for index,char in enumerate(font)}

# Use the translate method to modify each character according to the map
print("Converted:", input().translate(mapping))
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to learn more about `str.translate`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hoping to convert the input to each of three different fonts. In which case:

```
original = ""

alternative = [
    "",
    "",
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
]

text = ''

for a in alternative:
    t = ''
    for c in text:
        if (i := original.find(c)) >= 0:
            t += a[i]
        else:
            t += c
    print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
APPLE
```